# Android edit stored .html page

Tags: java, android, html

I have a locally stored HTML file in my assets folder that I am accessing through this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    WebView webView = new WebView(this);
    setContentView(webView);
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test.html");
}
```

I was wondering if there is any way I would be able to edit the source of the `HTML` file loaded, as I may need to manipulate certain elements.

**ex.** I have a `<h3>Johny</h3>` in the **test.html**, How can I change it by using an **edittext**?

I know how to use and show and get results form an **edittext**, but then, how to replace what is from the **edittext** to the `<h3>` tags in replacement to **Johny**?

Comment: Load the html file from assets in a `String source` variable. Then do a `source = source.replace("<h3>Johny</h3>", "<h3>" + editText.getText().toString() + "</h3>");` Finally `webView.loadUrl(..., source, ...);`.

Comment: that looks like what I am looking for, but I didn't understand the first part though .. how to load the html file in a string source?

Comment: Look for code on this site to copy a file from assets to internal or external memory. That code is easy adaptable to put it in a String instead of a file.

Comment: Why do you think so? What is the problem? What does file size matter? A String variable can easily contain a mega byte.

Comment: I have done it, thank you very much for your tip.